# How do I make Mypy recognize non-nullable ORM attributes?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, mypy

Mypy infers ORM non-nullable instance attributes as optionals.

Filename: `test.py`

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import decl_api, registry
from sqlalchemy import BigInteger, Column, String

mapper_registry = registry()


class Base(metaclass=decl_api.DeclarativeMeta):
    __abstract__ = True

    registry = mapper_registry
    metadata = mapper_registry.metadata

    __init__ = mapper_registry.constructor


class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = "persons"

    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String(40), nullable=False)


def main(person: Person):
    person_id = person.id
    person_name = person.name

    reveal_locals()
```

Running `mypy test.py` yields:

```
test.py:27: note: Revealed local types are:
test.py:27: note:     person: test.Person
test.py:27: note:     person_id: Union[builtins.int, None]
test.py:27: note:     person_name: Union[builtins.str, None]
```

As far as my understanding goes, `person_id` and `person_name` should have been `int` and `str` respectively since they are set as non-nullable.

What am I missing here?

---

Relevant libraries:

```
SQLAlchemy         1.4.25
sqlalchemy2-stubs  0.0.2a15
mypy               0.910
mypy-extensions    0.4.3
```

Comment: Have you read [this](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/mypy.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same question when evaluating a `nullable=False` column with mypy.  One of my teammates found the answer in the SqlAlchemy docs:

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/mypy.html#introspection-of-columns-based-on-typeengine

> The types are by default always considered to be Optional, even for
> the primary key and non-nullable column. The reason is because while
> the database columns “id” and “name” can’t be NULL, the Python
> attributes id and name most certainly can be None without an explicit
> constructor:

There are also mitigations they list in that article with declaring the columns to be mapped types explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 possible work around.

Use next "ugly" checks for None

```
def main(person: Person):
    if person.id is None or person.name is None:
        _msg = "not fully initialized Person obj, some field is None"
        raise RuntimeError(_msg)

    person_id: int = person.id
    person_name: str = person.name
```

You can add "strict" properties on orm model like here

```
class Trip(BaseModel):
    aircraft_id: int | None
    
    @property
    def aircraft_id_strict(self) -> int:
    if self.aircraft_id is None:
         raise Exception
    return self.aircraft_id

await _get_currencies(session=session, data=data, aircraft_id=trip.aircraft_id_strict)
```

Use DTO

```
class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = "persons"

    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String(40), nullable=False)    


class PersonDTO(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str
    
    class Config:
        orm_mode = True


async def get_person(session: AsyncSession, person_id: int) -> PersonDTO:
    q = select(Person).where(Person.id == person_id)
    result = await session.execute(q)
    person = result.scalar_one_or_none()
    if person is None:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="Person not found")
    return PersonDTO.from_orm(person)
```